# NHibernate SQLite encoding

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, nhibernate-mapping

I have set up my NHibernate app to use SQLite as the backend database for a small project. I'm using mapping by code to connect my entities to the database. Everything works fine but one thing: the data returned from the database has no Croatian special characters. When opening the database with SQLite administrator, the characters are shown correctly, but when fetched via a NHibernate Linq query, the special characters are shown as a black box with a question mark in it. I am using the following connection string:

```
"Data Source=D:\DATA\TEST.DB;version=3";
```

Is there any setup needed (in the database, the connection string or somewhere else) to make the characters show up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using connection string with predefined encoding settings:

```
"Data Source=D:\DATA\TEST.DB;version=3;UseUTF8Encoding=True;"
```

Comment: Dario, thanks for your suggestion. I already tried the UseUTF8Encoding attribute, both with true and false. After some more detailed investigation, the problem seems to be with the imported data. I did the importing via the SQLite Administrator tool from an MS Access database. When looking at the imported data in the SQLite Administrator browser, it looks just fine, but all other software won't show the special characters from the imported data. I entered some data programatically and they are interpreted correctly. So, the import seems to be the culprit.